# how to import magento orders into quickbooks desktop enterpise edition using web connector?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, quickbooks, qbxml

How to import orders from magento site to quickbooks desktop enterprise edition using web connector ?

there was example in the `devkit/docs/example_web_connector_import.php`  for importing data from quickbooks to mysql db

but there is no example to import the orders, customers and products form magento site / mysql db to the qucikbooks using web connector

anyone guide me how import the orders, customers and products form magento site to the qucikbooks using web connector

**Another question** regarding `enqueue()` method.

If we queued a process that process won't run instantly right?

It will run only based on the time we set for the application in the web connector program like to run every 2 minutes is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but there is no example to import the orders, customers and products
>   form magento site / mysql db to the qucikbooks using web connector

Yes there is.

This example shows how to add customers and sales receipts to QuickBooks:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php

There's a more fleshed out example here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector

> If we queued a process that process won't run instantly right?

Correct. That's what a queue is - a list of things to do in the future.

> It will run only based on the time we set for the application in the
>   web connector program like to run every 2 minutes is that right?

Correct.

Comment: Hi Keith, 
Thanks for the reply 
so is there any other option other than queue method to do things instantly

here while adding a customer we need to check weather that customer exits in the quickbook or not,if customer exists we need the data of him to add a sale order to quickbook 

if the customer doesn't exits in the QB we will add the customer first and then sales order of that customer to the QB

Comment: If you're using the Web Connector, you have to use a queue. What you described (checking if a customer exists, adding the customer if not, then adding a sales order) is perfectly possible using a queue. The queue is a priority queue, so you can queue up a CustomerQuery with a priority of 10, and a SalesOrderAdd with a priority of 0. When you get the response back from QuickBooks for the CustomerQuery, queue up a CustomerAdd with a priority of 5 if it doesn't exist. So you'd end up with either of these two scenarios: CustomerQuery, CustomerAdd, SalesOrderAdd OR CustomerQuery, SalesOrderAdd.

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte : Both links in above given answer is not working :(